# GStreamer doesn't show video over an udp stream connection

Tags: gstreamer

Following a tutorial in Portuguese on [Youtube](https://youtu.be/KLhZmEGeqHk?t=688), executed commands were:

**Source:**

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc \
! decodebin \
! x264enc \
! rtph264pay \
! udpsink host=localhost port=7001
```

**Sink:**

```
gst-launch-1.0 \
udpsrc port=7001 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" \
! rtph264depay \
! decodebin \
! videoconvert \
! autovideosink
```

And it worked for him, a video was displayed over udp connection, in my case it doesn't show anything.

**Results:**

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Got context from element 'autovideosink0': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"\(GstGLDisplayX11\)\ gldisplayx11-0";
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
```

Running in an Ubuntu 20.04 fresh installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by changing `host=localhost` to `host=127.0.0.1`